# "Expected type 'Union[str, bytearray]' got 'int' instead" warning in write method

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

My script writes to file chunk by chunk, using pre-generated data patterns:

```
#  Data pattern generator    
def get_random_chunk_pattern():
            return ''.join(random.choice(ascii_uppercase + digits + ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(8))
```

....

```
# DedupChunk class CTOR:
class DedupChunk:
    def __init__(self, chunk_size, chunk_pattern, chunk_position=0, state=DedupChunkStates.PENDING):
        self._chunk_size = chunk_size  # chunk size in bytes
        self._chunk_pattern = chunk_pattern
        self._chunk_position = chunk_position
        self._state = state
        self.mapping = None

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._chunk_size

    @property
    def pattern(self):
        return self._chunk_pattern

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self._chunk_position

    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state
```

....

```
# Here Chunk object is being initialized (inside other class's CTOR):
chunk_size = random.randint(64, 192) * 1024  # in bytes
        while (position + chunk_size) < self.file_size:  # generating random chunks number
            self.chunks.append(DedupChunk(chunk_size, DedupChunkPattern.get_random_chunk_pattern(), position))
```

....

```
# Actual writing
    with open(self.path, 'rb+') as f:
        for chunk in self.chunks:
            f.write(chunk.pattern * (chunk.size // 8))
```

`PyCharm` displays "`Expected type 'Union[str, bytearray]'  got 'int' instead`" warning in write method

But when removing the division in
`f.write(chunk.pattern * chunk.size)`,  or doing division outside:

```
chunk.size //= 8
f.write(chunk.pattern * chunk.size)
```

warning disappeared

What actually happened here?

Thanks

Comment: well,first of all, `chunk.size` and `chunk_size` are not the same thing...

Comment: Oops my mistake.  Updating

Comment: Without knowing the contents and type of `chunk.pattern`, it's hard to know what's going on. Can you write `chunk.pattern` to file without the multiplication?

Comment: @Evert chunk.pattern is inialised by get_random_chunk_pattern( )

Comment: I'm guessing that your chunk.pattern is somehow return an int rather than what you think it is. Try explicitly converting into a string with `str(chunk.pattern *(chunk.size // 8))` and see what you get

Comment: We don't get to see the assignments of chunk.pattern and chunk.size, so we just have to take your word for it those are correct; which may not be the case, but we can't tell.

Comment: You should debug your script by printing the value and types of both chunk.pattern and chuck.size.

Comment: @Evert Thank You, Updated my question. Hopefully it will help :)

Comment: @RNar Thanks, Updated my question

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ignore this warning. The IDE is making a best guess (from limited information) as to what the data type will be at runtime, but it is guessing wrong. That is, it is fairly reasonable to expect that something multiplied by an `int` will result in an `int` if you don't know what that something actually is.

If you really want to solve this then tell the IDE what you expect `chunk.pattern` to be by writing a doc string for your class (or using annotations to provide type hinting).

eg.

```
class DedupChunk:
    """
    :type _chunk_pattern: str
    ... other fields
    """
    ... # rest of class
```

With newer versions of python, then the preferred syntax would be:

```py
class DedupChunk:
    def __init__(self,
            chunk_pattern: str,
            # ... more args
    ):
        self._chunk_pattern = chunk_pattern
        ... # rest of class
```

For local variables or class variables you can annotate the variables.

```py
# given f() has an unknown return type

foo: str = f()  # annotate as type str and initalise
bar: str        # only annotate as type str, but leave uninitialised

class MyClass:
    foo: str = f()
    bar: str
```

Comment: Any way to do variable type hinting using inline comment instead of in a docstring?

Comment: what if the class is an inheritance from other class, what type we should declare? I have tried to declare the type of any properties from its parent class, but the warning still there.

Answer (score 10):

To ignore the warning inline, add this comment above the line causing the warning

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
```