# Python Warning - Expected type 'Union[Integral, slice]', got 'str' instead

Tags: python, dictionary, types, pycharm, warnings

My code below in python is giving me a warning on the line:

```
 some_new_object['someVar'] = cd['someVar']
```

The warning is

```
Expected type 'Union[Integral, slice]', got 'str' instead
```

Code:

```
def some_object():
     return {
         'someId': 0,
         'someVar' : ''
     }

def warn_test(in_list):
     try:
         new_list = []
         some_new_object = some_object()

         for cd in in_list:
             if cd['someVar']:
                 new_list.append(cd)

         for cd in new_list:
             some_new_object['someVar'] = cd['someVar']
             in_list.append(some_new_object.copy())

         return in_list
     except Exception:
         print 'baaa'

 #Main Program
 new_obj =  some_object()
 new_obj['someId'] = 1
 new_obj['someVar'] = 'Next'

 new_obj2 =  some_object()
 new_obj2['someId'] = 1
 new_obj2['someVar'] = None

 new_list = []
 new_list.append(new_obj)
 new_list.append(new_obj2)

 out_list = warn_test(new_list)
 for obj in out_list:
     print obj
```

If I change the function warn_test to this:

```
def warn_test(in_list):
    try:
        new_list = []
        some_new_object = some_object()

        for cd in in_list:
            if cd['someVar']:
                some_new_object['someVar'] = cd['someVar']
                new_list.append(some_new_object.copy())

        for cd in new_list:
            in_list.append(cd)

        return in_list
    except Exception:
        print 'baaa'
```

It gives me no warning.

Can someone help me to understand why I get the warning, and how I can access the `cd['someVar']` in the second iteration without getting a warning?

I know this code is weird, I need this for a project I am working on, I made this test to share here, but it gives me the same Warning so a solution for this will fix it in my system.  (No warnings is one of the Must Haves for this system)

Comment: `some_new_object` is an object not dict. however, you can set attribute using `setattr(obj, key, value)`

Comment: Is this a warning from pycharm?  If so please show _exactly_ which line in your code triggers the warning, then maybe someone can work out why the type-checker doesn't like it.

Comment: Similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33392413/5381704

Comment: Yes I am using pycharm. I posted the line that is giving the warning: 

some_new_object['someVar'] = cd['someVar']

In the warnTest method.  That would be line 17 in the first code block I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

In general I have found that if variables/method returns are strongly typed these warnings go away.

Comment: things like methods: def the_method(self, file_path: str) -> (list, list, int, int):

things like variables: list_a: list = [], the_number: int, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
def some_object() -> dict:
     return {
         'someId': 0,
         'someVar' : ''
     }

def warn_test(in_list):
     try:
         new_list = []
         some_new_object: dict = some_object()
```

you need to make clear that type of `some_new_object` is dict