# Python output of function to json issue

Tags: python, airflow

I have a function that return value and the value does have many fields in json, this is how I tried to call it since i'm using airflow python callable so I need to pass the function name their.

```
 def testing():
    resource = myaws.describe_clusters(
        ClusterIdentifier=name_of_cluster,
    )
    cluster_name = resource['Clusters'][0]['ClusterIdentifier']
    cluster_status = resource['Clusters'][0]['ClusterStatus']
    if cluster_status == 'available':

        

> 1#return f"Cluster: {cluster_name} Successfully : {cluster_status}"
> 
> 2#return {"Cluster": cluster_name, "Status": cluster_status, "Restored": "Yes"}

    else:
        return {"Status": cluster_status, "Restored": "No"}
```

this is how the resource data looks like

```
{'Clusters': [{'ClusterIdentifier': 'name_of_cluster', 'ClusterStatus': 'available',
```

When I call this function in python callable "airflow"  operator I get error as

**TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable**

both return 1 and return number 2 gives same error, i'm confused as second output is json format even when I print the second return I see it as bellow, I have commented the return and give it number to be clear.

Returned value was: {'Cluster': 'name_of_cluster', 'Status': 'available', 'Restored': 'Yes'}

when I call this function in my IDE it also give me hint like, my IDE is pycharm by googling it says it might be false positive but I don't know this might give you guys more details.

```
Expected type 'str', got '() -> Union[str, Dict[str, Union[str, Any]]]' instead
```

Thank you for help

Comment: I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33392413/14994144) could solve your issue.

Comment: No, it did not as the method still give that serialized error, even-though  I ignored the IDE hint